# auto arima with stepAIC and PCA

Tags: arima

Can auto arima be used in conjunction with stepAIC or principal components analysis? I have several regressors and I don't know which ones to use in auto arima. I was hoping to use stepAIC to help me in this but I don't know how exactly to use it in the context of auto arima. Can someone help me with this? For pure regression, its use is simple; it's just used on the full model.